# command to get filelist ordered by age (mtime) in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to simply process a list of files in a directory using Tcl, but want to process them in age order (oldest mtime to newest).  I expected some sort of argument in glob or lsort to sort by file mtime, but I don't see such option.

I am trying to avoid creating a custom function to do this

Is there an option which I am missing that will do this built-in?

Comment: Why are you trying "to avoid creating a custom function"?

Comment: @andymango I don't mind creating a custom procedure if there is no standard function, but if there is, why wouldn't I want to use that instead of generating a custom version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I know of, but you could of course `exec` your system's file listing command with the appropriate options.

Taking the mtime is a fairly expensive operation, so applications that use it typically take shortcuts to avoid querying for it. Making it portable also adds overhead.

Anyway, it's easy to implement it:

```
set files [glob x*]
set fileAndMTime [lmap name $files {list $name [file mtime $name]}]
lmap item [lsort -integer -index 1 $fileAndMTime] {lindex $item 0}
```

The last line gives you a list of filenames, sorted in order of least mtime to greatest mtime (use `-decreasing` to reverse order, and note that the sort is stable).

Documentation:
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm),
[glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm)

Comment: thanks.  I guess I just assumed that such a fundamental option should have existed already.

Comment: @Jonjilla: mostly it doesn't exist because it *isn't* a fundamental feature. It's a high-level feature that is best implemented in the application.

Comment: The OS APIs don't return the mtime when you list the contents of a directory. Some filetype information is present sometimes in the results of [`readdir(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) but no time information at all; also, the `stat()` family of system calls don't include anything that lets you give a file by inode (and device) so you're not going to save an OS-level lookup anyway.