# get latest version using tcl script

Tags: tcl, expression

Nuke is an application for compositing image sequence and mov's. Its nodes attributes for file path allows tcl scripts to 
replace the actual file from folder a "/show/ABCD/shot/HJ/HJ0022/edt/publish/editref/v002"

/show/ABCD/shot/HJ/HJ0022/edt/publish/editref/v002/HJ0022.hj.seq.234233.mov

this can be retrieved using tcl expression

```
[lindex [lsort -increasing [glob -nocomplain /show/[getenv SHOW]/shot/[getenv SEQ]/[getenv SHOT]/edt/publish/editref/v002/*.mov]
```

Question is :

Say there are multiple folders

```
/show/ABCD/shot/HJ/HJ0022/edt/publish/editref/v002
/show/ABCD/shot/HJ/HJ0022/edt/publish/editref/v003
/show/ABCD/shot/HJ/HJ0022/edt/publish/editref/v004
/show/ABCD/shot/HJ/HJ0022/edt/publish/editref/v005
```

How does one get latest folder v005 using tcl expression in single line as above. ~

I tried using regexp

```
[lindex [lsort -increasing [glob -nocomplain /show/[getenv SHOW]/shot/[getenv SEQ]/[getenv SHOT]/edt/publish/editref/[regexp -inline "v[0-9]{3}" [value Read1.file] ]/*.mov]
```

where Read1 is the name of the read node but apparently this is not correct and hunch is that 
it is not a proper way to implement it. What is the correct way to use regexp here or is their another way to get a file from latest version folder ~

Answer (score 2):

> How does one get latest folder v005 using tcl expression in single
>   line as above.

Assuming the list of file paths is `lsort`'ed, use `lindex` for it:

```
lindex [lsort -increasing $files] end
```

or

```
lindex [lsort -decreasing $files] 0
```

This extends to other sorting scenarios, see, e.g.: [command to get filelist ordered by age (mtime) in Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456446/command-to-get-filelist-ordered-by-age-mtime-in-tcl)

Comment: You might want to consider the differences of `lsort` flags (case-sensitivity etc.), depending on your environment.

Comment: Thank you. Your reply triggered to think more. This seems to work. [glob -type f [lindex [lsort -increasing [glob -nocomplain  /show/[getenv SHOW]/shot/[getenv SEQ]/[getenv SHOT]/edt/publish/editref/]] end]/*.mov]